アノテーションでフォーマッターを指定した時に未入力時のPatternバリデーションが効かなくなってしまう
必須項目に対して入力パターンの文字数制限を１〜N桁とすることで必須チェックを行なっていますが、アノテーションでフォーマッターを指定したフィールドで未入力時のPatternバリデーションが効かなくなってしまう現象に悩まされています。
デバッグ実行で見てると未入力項目ではフォーマッターのロジックを通ってないようです。
また、フォーマッターを指定したフィールドはNullが設定され、フォーマッターを指定していないフィールドには空文字””が設定されます。
解決策はあるでしょうか？
(@NotNullや@NotBlankは効くのでダメならそれで逃げます。)
  @Data
  public class ValidateForm implements Serializable {
  /**
   * 必須番号.
   * 必須9桁以内数値
   * フォーマッターを指定しない場合必須入力チェックになる
   */
  @Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]{1,9}$")
  private String requiredId;

  /**
   * 必須番号.
   * 必須9桁以内数値
   * フォーマッター(@SpaceTrim)を指定すると必須入力チェックにならない
   */
  @Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]{1,9}$")
  @SpaceTrim
  private String canNotRequiredId;

アノテーション定義
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface SpaceTrim {
}

フォーマッター
public class SpaceTrimFormatterFactory implements AnnotationFormatterFactory<SpaceTrim> {
  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getFieldTypes() {
    return Set.of(String.class);
  }

  @Override
  public Printer<?> getPrinter(SpaceTrim annotation, Class<?> fieldType) {
    return new SpaceTrimFormatter();
  }

  @Override
  public Parser<?> getParser(MyAnno annotation, Class<?> fieldType) {
    return new SpaceTrimFormatter();
  }

  private static class SpaceTrimFormatter implements Formatter<String> {
    @Override
    public String print(String object, Locale locale) {
      return object;
    }

    @Override
    public String parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
      return text == null ? null : text.trim();
    }
  }
}


雑に追っただけですが、AnnotationFormatterFactory があると内部的に空文字 "" が null に変換され、そのせいで @Pattern が無視されているように見えますね。
この issue で報告されている現象と同じだと思いますが、再現コードの提供がなかったのでクローズされてます。
再現コード（ユニットテストかデモプロジェクト）が用意できるようなら reopen してもらえると思います。
@Pattern と組み合わせたときの動作として報告した方が影響について理解しやすそうですが、その場合は新規 issue を作成した方が良いかも。

ave様コメントありがとうございます。Pomにはorg.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.2.3となっているのですが、このissueで議論されている6.0.4または6.0.6には該当しているのでしょうか？

外部ライブラリには「Maven: org.springframework:spring-core:6.1.4」がありました。

issue が上がっているのは少し古いバージョンですね。spring-boot は spring に依存していますが、バージョン番号が異なるので少々ややこしいです。

ave様のコメントで提示いただいたissueの現象が発生しているようです。
再度よくみたらFormにはどちらも空文字””が設定されているのですが、自前のバリデーションにはNullと空文字に分かれてしまってました。
なので、Formへの設定はこのissueのように解決できているが、バリデーションチェック時は未解決と思われます。
@NotNullチェックで逃げる方向で実装します。
ありがとうございました。
